# Smooth Scroll JQuery doesn't work smoothly in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this JQuery script for a vertical smooth scrolling effect. It works perfectly in Internet Explorer and Firefox but it's not smooth at all in Google Chrome's latest version??? How come? Should I change something in the script or is there another smooth scroll script that works nice and smooth across all browsers?

In Google Chrome, the smooth scroll effect actually jiggles and stops for a brief moment so that it all looks kinda ugly.

Here is the JavaScript/JQuery code:

```
(function() {
    $('header ul a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top + "px"
        }, 1500);
        /*
        if you don't want to use the easing effects:
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        */
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My HTML has 5 `<section>`'s and each section has it's own ID (Home, About, Services, Gallery and Contact) so there is nothing spectacular here. Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or your web link? It will be hard to figure it out without seeing the problem

Comment: I'll try to do it, but as I said above everything works excellent in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, but maybe it's only an hardware limitation of your computer. We still have to see it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/uNKmz/17/

Comment: Home and Services sections actually have a photobackground but that's not important here. Everything is smooth in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome :(

Comment: I hate to break it to you but my Chrome runs it smooth as butter. Do you have a lot of "Developer" plugins in your Chrome browser? I know in Firefox firebug can slow things down sometimes. I am only running AdBlock Lite in Chrome btw

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Glad to hear it works fine in your Chrome but it doesn't works smoothly in mine for some reason. I actually use Firefox all the time but I just wanted to test the code in IE and Chrome and then I noticed that it doesn't work properly in Chrome at my computer. Not sure what causes the problem :(

Comment: Where can I check for those Developer plugins in Chrome?

Comment: I just checked my Chrome and it says: Boo... You have no extensions. Hehe~ Probably because I never use the Chrome. Still my problem persist and smooth scroll is not smooth...

Comment: It may be a localized issue with your computer. Try uninstalling/re-installing Chrome. Do you have access to another computer with chrome?

Comment: I'll try it on another computer but cannot do it now. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: No problem, I just found an article about GPU Acceleration so maybe it's worth a shot. http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/03/03/speed-up-google-chrome-by-enabling-hardware-acceleration-and-pre/

Comment: Ill read it too. Thanks!